# Bundler using an older Ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I have Ruby 2.3.0 installed in my system. The output of `ruby -v` is:

```
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]
```

When I try to run Rails using:

```
bundle exec rails new ~/my-test-app --dev
```

I get the following error:

```
Your Ruby version is 2.1.7, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.0
```

I have both Ruby versions installed. How to make bundle use Ruby 2.3.0 instead of 2.1.7

Comment: Add the output of `gem env` to your question, formatted appropriately. How do you have two Rubies installed? If you're using RVM or rbenv then you version manager isn't installed correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR Change the version of Ruby from 2.1 to 2.3 in /usr/local/bin/bundle.

**Explanation**

To figure out which Ruby bundler is using enter

```
which bundle
```

This should print

> /usr/local/bin/bundle

Now open the file and change the Ruby version from 2.1 to 2.3

Answer (score 1):

Run `gem install bundler` should fix this for you.

Then remember `rbenv rehash`

Reload `'bashrc' file` if the problem is still there.

Comment: What do you mean by reload bashrc file?

Comment: It didn't fix the problem

Comment: try `spring stop` as well. Your spring may still be running on 2.1.7